# Sum aggregation over list items in Django JSONField

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

I'd like to calculate the sum of all elements in a list inside a [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField) via Django's ORM. The objects basically look like this:

```json
[
  {"score": 10},
  {"score": 0},
  {"score": 40},
  ...
]
```

There are several problems that made me use a [Raw Query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries) in the end (see SQL query below) but I'd like to know if it is possible with Django's ORM.

```sql
SELECT id,
       SUM(elements.score) AS total_score
FROM my_table,
LATERAL (SELECT
  (jsonb_array_elements('results')->'score')::integer AS score
) AS elements
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY total_score DESC
```

The main problems I faced is that the list in the JSONField needs to be turned into a set via `jsonb_array_elements`. Afterwards it is impossible to run an aggregate function over the results. Postgres complains:

> aggregate function calls cannot contain set-returning function calls

Using a `LATERAL FROM` -- as widely suggested -- is not possible with the ORM. Not even with Django's [.extra() queryset method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) because it is not possible to specify an additional table that is not quoted in the final query:

```py
Model.objects.annotate(...).extra(
    tables="LATERAL (SELECT (jsonb_array_elements('results')->'score')::integer AS score) AS elements"
)
# ERROR: no relation "LATERAL (SELECT ..."
```

Answer (score 2):

You can annotate the queryset with the score value from the `JSONField`, `Cast` it to an integer, retrieve the `distinct` values, and get the `sum` of whatever is left. I think the following query should do the trick:

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.db.models.fields.json import KeyTextTransform
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

Model.objects.annotate(
    score=Cast(
        KeyTextTransform("score", "JSONField_name"),
        IntegerField(),
    )
).values("score").distinct().aggregate(Sum("score"))["score__sum"]
```

Note that you will still have to change the `JSONField_name` according to your model

Comment: Thanks for your helping out. I had a look at what `KeyTextTransform` does and it seems that it is an abstraction for the `->>` and `#>>` operators that perform path lookups. `KeyTextTransform("key", "field_name"))` doesn't return anything if the field contains a list. `KeyTextTransform("0", "field_name"))` returns the first list entry but I need to retrieve the same field from _all_ list items in that JSONField.